Why $\infty=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+i}\neq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n+i}=\log2$?
I was wondering why $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+i}$ diverges but $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n+i}=\log2$. While assuming integral as limit of series, we find out that:
$$
\int_1^2\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum\left(f;P_n^*\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf(\xi_i)(t_i-t_{i-1}), f(x)=\frac{1}{x}
$$
where $\xi_i\in[t_{i-1},t_i]$ and $P_n^*=\{t_0,...,t_{i-1},t_i,...,t_n\}$ is a partition of $[1,2]$, assuming $t_0=1$ and $t_n=2$. Forcing $t_i=\frac{n+i}{n}=1+\frac{i}{n}$, then $t_i-t_{i-1}=1+\frac{i}{n}-(1+\frac{i-1}{n})=\frac{1}{n}$ and $f(\xi_i)=\frac{1}{\xi_i}$. Considering $\xi_i=t_i$ we have:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf(\xi_i)(t_i-t_{i-1})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\frac{n+i}{n}}\frac{1}{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n+i}
$$
By one hand this is equals to $\int_1^2\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}$, which is equals to $\log2$, by other hand $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+i}$ is supposed to diverge as $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i}$ diverges.
I'm asking what's wrong here.
See below to notice by yourselves this paradox:

Valuation of $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+i}$, per WolframAlpha

Valuation of $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n+i}$, per WolframAlpha



Why do you think there is anything "wrong here"? In the first case, the sum is over an infinite number of terms, while in the second case, you're only summing over $n$ terms (each of which in turn is $<1/n$). These are simply different series, there's nothing paradoxical about the fact that they behave differently.

The same "paradox" is shown by $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n$.  The limit is $e$.  We can't send only the $n$ inside the parentheses to infinity as that would give $1$, and we cannot send only the $n$ in the exponent to infinity as that would give infinity.  No paradox if you break the rules to reach it.

The big difference is that in the first $n$ is a constant unrelated to indexing cap.  The second the $n$ varies with the indexing cap.  The first is $\lim_{M\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}\frac 1{n+k}$. $n$ is just an arbitrary constant value and has nothing to do with the limit. and other is $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{n+k}$.  Do you see the difference?

Compare it to these two $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac 1n^2 = \lim_{M\to \infty}\frac 1{n^2} = \lim_{M \to \infty} M\times \frac 1{n^2}$ which, as $\frac 1{n^2}$ is a positive constant that has nothing to do with $M$ must be $\infty$; and $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{n^2} = \lim_{n\to\infty} n\times \frac 1{n^2} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac 1n = 0$.  The difference there is $n$ is not a constant unrelated to the variable we are taking a limit of, but is the variable we are  taking the limit of.  ENTIRELY different.

One can not just simply changes n to infinity as pleasure. I finaly got the idea.

The biggest issue here in my opinion is that, in the expression
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n+i}
$$
two things are being taken to $\infty$: the upper bound of the sum, and the $n$ in the summand. That is, more generally,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f(n;i)
\ne \sum_{i=1}^\infty f(n;i)
$$
because the latter expression still has an $n$ in it, if absolutely nothing else. If equality were to hold, it would only be for very special functions $f$. Perhaps even more generally,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{f(n),g(n)}
\ne \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} a_{f(n),g(m)}
$$
for appropriate (say, increasing and integer-valued) functions $f,g$ and a double-sequence $a_{i,j}$.

All this to say: if you are taking a limit in some variable, you can't just apply that limit to one place where the variable is at a time. This would be an example of that.

An example is in the comments already: a famous limit is
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^n = e
$$
but some will claim
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^n \stackrel ? = 
 \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right) \right)^{\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n}
\stackrel ? = 1^\infty
$$
by bringing the limit into the parenthetical and the exponent. And if they only do one of those first, they'll say "$1$ to the anything is $1$" or "Something larger than $1$ to the $\infty$ power is $\infty$," but using our rigorous definitions we can prove neither of these claims is right.

When $n$ goes to infinity, every $n$ in the expression goes to infinity, at the same time, at the same rate.

